# Practical difference between parser rules and lexer rules in ANTLR?

Tags: parsing, antlr, lexical-analysis

I understand the theory behind separating parser rules and lexer rules in theory, but what are the practical differences between these two statements in ANTLR:

```
my_rule: ... ;

MY_RULE: ... ;
```

Do they result in different AST trees?  Different performance?  Potential ambiguities?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

> ... what are the practical differences between these two statements in ANTLR ...

`MY_RULE` will be used to tokenize your input source. It represents a fundamental building block of your language.

`my_rule` is called from the parser, it consists of zero or more other parser rules or tokens produced by the lexer.

That's the difference.

> Do they result in different AST trees? Different performance? ...

The parser builds the AST using tokens produced by the lexer, so the questions make no sense (to me). A lexer merely "feeds" the parser a 1 dimensional stream of tokens.

Comment: Performance-wise I understood the questions in a sense if it is better to write: `my_rule : 'a'?'b';` or `MY_TOKEN : 'ab' | 'b';`. Both match the same but how fast? Intuitively I would expect the latter to be a bit faster but I might be wrong.

Answer (score 12):

This post may be helpful:

> The lexer is responsible for the first step, and it's *only* job is to
> create a "token stream" from text. It is not responsible for
> understanding the semantics of your language, it is only interested in
> understanding the syntax of your language.
>
> For example, syntax is the rule that an identifier must only use
> characters, numbers and underscores - as long as it doesn't start with
> a number. The responsibility of the lexer is to understand this rule.
> In this case, the lexer would accept the sequence of characters
> "asd_123" but reject the characters "12dsadsa" (assuming that there
> isn't another rule in which this text is valid). When seeing the valid
> text example, it may emit a token into the token stream such as
> IDENTIFIER(asd_123).
>
> Note that I said "identifier" which is the general term for things
> like variable names, function names, namespace names, etc. The parser
> would be the thing that would understand the context in which that
> identifier appears, so that it would then further specify that token
> as being a certain thing's name.
>
> (sidenote: the token is just a unique name given to an element of the
> token stream. The lexeme is the text that the token was matched from.
> I write the lexeme in parentheses next to the token. For example,
> NUMBER(123). In this case, this is a NUMBER token with a lexeme of
> '123'. However, with some tokens, such as operators, I omit the lexeme
> since it's redundant. For example, I would write SEMICOLON for the
> semicolon token, not SEMICOLON( ; )).

From [ANTLR - When to use Parser Rules vs Lexer Rules?](https://web.archive.org/web/20170518183925/https://www.3dbuzz.com/forum/threads/203932-ANTLR-When-to-use-Parser-Rules-vs-Lexer-Rules)

Comment: Thank you for posting Dave. This link was incredibly helpful!