# The following alternatives can never be reached: 2

Tags: java, antlr, grammar, antlrworks

I'm trying to create a very simple grammar to learn to use ANTLR but I get the following message:

*"The following alternatives can never be reached: 2"*

This is my grammar attempt:

```
grammar Robot;

file    :   command+;
command :   ( delay|type|move|click|rclick) ;
delay   :   'wait' number ';';
type    :   'type' id ';';
move    :   'move' number ',' number ';';
click   :   'click' ;
rclick  :   'rlick' ;
id  :       ('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z')+ ;
number  :       ('0'..'9')+ ;
WS  :   (' ' | '\t' | '\r' | '\n' ) { skip();} ;
```

I'm using ANTLRWorks plugin for IDEA:

[image: This is what it looks like]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `..` (range) inside parser rules means something different than inside lexer rules. Inside lexer rules, it means: "from char X to char Y", and inside parser rule it matches "from token M to token N". And since you made `number` a parser rule, it does not do what you think it does (and are therefor receiving an obscure error message).

The solution: make `number` a lexer rule instead (so, capitalize it: `Number`):

```
grammar Robot;

file    :   command+;
command :   (delay | type | move | Click | RClick) ;
delay   :   'wait' Number ';';
type    :   'type' Id ';';
move    :   'move' Number ',' Number ';';
Click   :   'click' ;
RClick  :   'rlick' ;
Id      :   ('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z')+ ;
Number  :   ('0'..'9')+ ;
WS      :   (' ' | '\t' | '\r' | '\n') { skip();} ;
```

And as you can see, I also made `id`, `click` and `rclick` lexer rules instead. If you're not sure what the difference is between parser- and lexer rules, please say so and I'll add an explanation to this answer.

Comment: BTW what's the convention `Number` or `NUMBER` ?

Comment: @Oscar, there's no real convention. However, at a later stage (more complicated grammars), you're likely to use so called "imaginary tokens", which I like to distinguish from "normal" tokens. So I use all-caps for imaginary tokens and a single capital for "normal" tokens (token == lexer rule). Whatever fancies you though...

Comment: *If you're not sure what the difference is between parser- and lexer rules, please say so and I'll add an explanation to this answer.*  Actually I don't  :P  I *think* I know but I wouldn't mind  to read your explanation

Comment: I was about to create a new question for this and I found: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4297770/practical-difference-between-parser-rules-and-lexer-rules-in-antlr/4298122#4298122

Comment: @Oscar, I can never find any of my previous answers, so I was about to edit my current answer and add an explanation! :) Good to see you _can_ find stuff on SO!

Comment: Same happens to me.. I think the search when you create a question is slightly different from the regular search.  At least that's the impression I have.

Comment: I asked on meta http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/94674/do-the-search-in-new-question-work-different-to-the-regular-search

Comment: Thanks, will keep an eye on it.