# How to resolve this parsing ambiguitiy in Antlr3

Tags: antlr, antlr3, antlrworks

Hopefully this is just the right amount of information to help me solve this problem.

Given the following ANTLR3 syntax

```
grammar mygrammar;

program : statement* | function*;

function : ID '(' args ')' '->' statement+ (','statement+) '.' ;    

args    : arg (',' arg)*;       

arg     : ID ('->' expression)?;

statement : assignment
          | number
          | string
          ;

assignment : ID '->' expression;    

string  : UNICODE_STRING;

number : HEX_NUMBER | INTEGER ( '.' INTEGER )?;


// ================================================================

HEX_NUMBER : '0x' HEX_DIGIT+;

INTEGER : DIGIT+;

fragment
DIGIT   :   ('0'..'9');
```

Here is the line that is causing problems in the parser.

```
my_function(x, y, z -> 42) -> 10001.
```

ANTLRWorks highlights the **last** `.` after the 10001 in red as being a problem with the following error.

How can I make this stop throwing `org.antlr.runtime.EarlyExitException`?

I am sure this is because of some ambiguity between my `number` parser rule and trying to use the `.` as a EOL delimiter.

Comment: Does putting the `number` rule first help?

Comment: @therefromhere, no, parser rules can be placed in any order: that doesn't make a difference. It's lexer rules whose order is important.

Comment: @Bart see my update to my question, the error is with the last `.`

Comment: @JarrodRoberson my bad, I'm a bit rusty with antlr!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is another ambiguity that also needs fixing. Change:

```
program : statement* | function*;
```

into:

```
program  : (statement | function)*;
```

*(although the 2 are not equivalent, I'm guessing you want the latter)*

And in your `function` rule, you now defined there to be at least 2 `statement`s:

```
function : ID '(' args ')' '->' statement (','statement)+ '.' ;
```

while I'm guessing you really want at least one:

```
function : ID '(' args ')' '->' statement (','statement)* '.' ;
```

Now, your real problem: since you're constructing floats in a parser rule, from the end of your input, `10001.`, the parser tries to construct a `number` of it, while you want it to match an `INTEGER` and then a `.`, as you yourself already said in your OP.

To fix this, you need to give the parser a bit of extra look-ahead to "see" beyond this ambiguity. Do that by adding the predicate `(INTEGER '.' INTEGER)=>` before actually matching said input:

```
number
  :  HEX_NUMBER 
  |  (INTEGER '.' INTEGER)=> INTEGER '.' INTEGER 
  | INTEGER
  ;
```

Now your input will generate the following parse tree:

[image]

Comment: is there a better way to detect the float numbers other than the way I am doing it?

Comment: @JarrodRoberson, there are various ways, but all have their draw-backs. The easiest would be to introduce a `FLOAT : DIGIT+ '.' DIGIT+;` in your lexer and change the fact that statements can end with a `'.'`. If you want to keep the `'.'` as a EOL, then the way you're doing it now (including my suggestions) is probably the easiest way to solve it.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps unrelated, but I'm curious none-the-less:

```
function : ID '(' args ')' '->' statement+ (','statement+) '.' ;
```

Should this instead be:

```
function : ID '(' args ')' '->' statement (',' statement)* '.' ;
```

I think the first one would require a single comma in a function definition but the second one would require a comma as a statement separator.

Also, does the rule for `args` allow `z -> 42` correctly?

Comment: @BartKiers (and sarnold) thanks for the input, I am really trying to grok ANTLR3, I have both the Terrance Parr books but the theory on the lexer and parser rules are still pretty opaque, I really appreciate the help!

Comment: @JarrodRoberson, you're welcome. Also see this previous Q&A about the difference between lexer- and parser rules: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4297770/practical-difference-between-parser-rules-and-lexer-rules-in-antlr