# Whats wrong in this grammar

Tags: antlr

I'm trying to write a grammar to parse an input of format

```
--
sfasfa af adfa
sfsdfsadfa
--
```

and this is what I came up with, but it says mismatchedTokenException.

```
grammar abc;

key :   MARK password MARK;

password:   char+ ;

char:   CHAR;

WS: (' '|'\r'|'\t'|'\u000C'|'\n') {channel=99;};

CHAR:   ('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z'|'0'..'9'|'/'|'+'|'='|'_'|'-'|':')*;

MARK    :   '--';
```

I want to fetch the password.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of things wrong:

- lexer rules should always match at least 1 char (your `CHAR` rule can match the empty string);
- the word `channel` should be preceded with a `$`;
- preferably, don't use magic numbers (not `99`, but `HIDDEN`).

Try:

```
grammar abc;

key      : HEADER password END;
password : char+ ;
char     : CHAR;
WS       : (' '|'\r'|'\t'|'\u000C'|'\n') {$channel=HIDDEN;};
CHAR     : ('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z'|'0'..'9'|'/'|'+'|'='|'_'|'-'|':');
HEADER   : '--BEGIN--';
END      : '--END--';
```

Comment: Thanks, That solved all the problems. 

Can you tell me whats the difference between lexer and parser rules?

Comment: @Buxme, have a look at this previous Q&A: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4297770/practical-difference-between-parser-rules-and-lexer-rules-in-antlr