# Match lowercase with ANTLR

Tags: antlr, antlrworks

I use ANTLRWorks for a simple grammar:

```
grammar boolean;

// [...]
lowercase_string
        :   ('a'..'z')+ ;
```

However, the `lowercase_string` doesn't match `foobar` according to the Interpreter (`MismatchedSetException(10!={})`. Ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't use the `..` operator inside parser rules like that. To match the range `'a'` to `'z'`, create a lexer rule for it (lexer rules start with a capital).

Try it like this:

```
lowercase_string
  :  Lower+ 
  ;

Lower
  :  'a'..'z'
  ;
```

or:

```
lowercase_string
  :  Lower
  ;

Lower
  :  'a'..'z'+
  ;
```

Also see this previous Q&A: [Practical difference between parser rules and lexer rules in ANTLR?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4297770/practical-difference-between-parser-rules-and-lexer-rules-in-antlr)