# Antlr and left-recursive rules

Tags: recursion, antlr, ambiguity

I am trying to write a grammar using ANTLR, but I can't understand how antlr works with recursive choices.

I read lots of articles and forums, but can't solve my problem...

Here is a small part of my grammar:

```
grammar MyGrammar;

ComponentRef :
    IDENT ('[' Expression (',' Expression)* ']')?
;

Expression:
    ComponentRef ('(' FunctionArguments ')')?
;

FunctionArguments:
    Expression (',' Expression)*
;

IDENT: ('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z'|'_') ('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z'|'_'|'0'..'9')*;
```

I still don't understand why it doesn't work... there is no ambiguity! Isn't it?

Here is some examples of code my grammar should work with :

```
a
a[b,c]
a[b[c], d]
func(a)
func(a,b,c)
func[a](b,c)
func(a[b], c[d])
func[a](b[c])
```

Thank you by advance!

Answer (score 6):

First, be sure to understand [lexer and parser rules](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4297770/59087). Also read the [ANTLR Mega Tutorial](https://tomassetti.me/antlr-mega-tutorial/).

The code only uses lexer rules, which won't work. Although even lexer rules *can* be recursive (in ANTLR grammars), they are best avoided. Rather, most rules should be parser rules:

```
componentRef :
    IDENT ('[' expression (',' expression)* ']')?
;

expression:
    componentRef ('(' functionArguments ')')?
;

functionArguments:
   expression (',' expression)*
;

IDENT: ('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z'|'_') ('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z'|'_'|'0'..'9')*;
```

The grammar above won't recognize the input you've posted, but there are no error anymore. A grammar that recognizes the input you've posted, could look like this (untested!) grammar:

```
parse
 : expr* EOF
 ;

expr
 : IDENT (index | call)*
 ;

index
 : '[' expr_list ']'
 ;

call
 : '(' expr_list ')'
 ;

expr_list
 : expr (',' expr)*
 ;

IDENT
 : ('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z'|'_') ('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z'|'_'|'0'..'9')*
 ;

SPACE
 : (' ' | '\t' | '\r' | '\n')+ {skip();}
 ;
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm assuming your capitol Expressions is an error.  You probably meant to type lowercase.

How can you say there's no ambiguity?  expressions call functionArguments, functionArguments calls expressions.  -1