# What's wrong with my simple antlr grammar?

Tags: java, antlr

I am trying to create a very simple antlr grammar file which should parse the following file:

```
Report (MyReport)
Begin
End
```

Or without report name:

```
Report
Begin
End
```

And here is my grammar file:

```
grammar RL;

options {
  language = Java;
}

report:
  REPORT ('(' SPACE* STRING_LITERAL SPACE* ')')?
  BEGIN
  END
  ;

REPORT
    :   'Report'
    ;     

BEGIN
    :   'Begin'
    ;

END :   'End';

NAME:   LETTER (LETTER | DIGIT | '_')*;

STRING_LITERAL :    NAME SPACE*;

fragment LETTER: LOWER | UPPER;

fragment LOWER: 'a'..'z';

fragment UPPER: 'A'..'Z';

fragment DIGIT: '0'..'9';

fragment SPACE: ' ' | '\t';

WHITESPACE: SPACE+ { $channel = HIDDEN; };

rule: ;
```

However when I debug in ANTLRWorks I always get the following error:

```
 root -> report -> MismatchedTokenException(0!=0)
```

What's wrong in my Grammar file?

thanks,
Green

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A couple of remarks:

- `Java` is the default language, so you can omit `language=Java;`;
- you're using `SPACE` inside a parser rule, while this `SPACE` token is a `fragment`: this causes the lexer never to create this token: remove it from your parser rule(s);
- the input `"Report "` ("Report" followed by a single white-space) is being tokenized as a `STRING_LITERAL`, not as a `REPORT`! ANTLR's lexer consumes characters greedily, only when two or more rules match the same amount of characters, the rule defined first will get precedence. The lexer does **not** produce tokens that the parser is trying to match (parsing and tokenization are being performed independently!).

Try the following instead:

```
grammar RL;

report
 : REPORT ('(' NAME ')')? BEGIN END
 ;

REPORT : 'Report';     
BEGIN  : 'Begin';
END    : 'End';
NAME   : LETTER (LETTER | DIGIT | '_')*;

fragment LETTER : LOWER | UPPER;
fragment LOWER  : 'a'..'z';
fragment UPPER  : 'A'..'Z';
fragment DIGIT  : '0'..'9';

SPACE  : (' ' | '\t' | '\r' | '\n')+ { $channel = HIDDEN; };
```

> ***green wrote:***
>
> What if I want to allow "SPACE" inside Report NAME?

I would still skip spaces in the lexer. Accepting spaces between names but ignoring them in other contexts will result in some clunky rules. Instead of accounting for spaces between a report's name, I would do something like this:

```
report
 : REPORT ('(' report_name ')')? BEGIN END
 ;

report_name
 : NAME+
 ;
```

resulting in the following parse tree:

[image]

for the input:

```
Report (a name with spaces)
Begin
End
```

> ***green wrote:***
>
> so is it possible to allow me use reserved words like 'Report' in the name?

Sure, explicitly add them in the `report_name` rule:

```
report_name
 : (NAME | REPORT | BEGIN | END)+
 ;
```

Comment: Thank you very much. What if I want to allow "SPACE" inside Report NAME?

Comment: I followed the "report_name" approach and get this error: "T:\tmp\RL\RL.g:11:1: The following token definitions can never be matched because prior tokens match the same input: REPORT_NAME". The source code is at https://gist.github.com/2991022

Comment: @green, no, you did not follow the approach. You used a lexer rule `REPORT_NAME` while I used a parser rule `report_name`. Be sure you understand the difference between the two: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4297770/practical-difference-between-parser-rules-and-lexer-rules-in-antlr

Comment: hmm... this is really tricky. thx a lot! Now I've make it works. The new problem is I can't use word "Report" in the report_name, it will report `UnwantedTokenException(found=Report)`. I think it's because i've defined `REPORT : 'Report';`, so is it possible to allow me use reserved words like 'Report' in the name?

Comment: @green, see my revised answer.