# define a terminal called 'message' to handle "\n" , nightmare ..

Tags: antlr, antlr3, antlrworks, antlrv3ide

i use a definition so called

```
message : '"'.* '"';
```

that represents every little thing inside " " is message , terminals 
it works well with "lkjaldjfa kajf " something common 
but when i met "\n" it turns to a nightmare -- which cause infinitive loop ,eat up my memory .

I dont know why .. thanks

Comment: Hi! For answer your question, need to see other Lexer rules in your gram.

Answer (score 1):

> ... it turns to a nightmare -- which cause infinitive loop, eat up my memory.

Hard to comment on that without being able to reproduce it.

However, the *parser* rule:

```
message : '"' .* '"';
```

matches the **token** `'"'` followed by zero or more other **tokens** ending with the **token** `'"'`.

Unless you have a very good reason to keep it as a parser rule (which I'd like to hear then), change it to a *lexer* rule:

```
Message : '"' .* '"';
```

which matches  the **character** `'"'` followed by zero or more other **characters** ending with the **character** `'"'`.

---

Also see: [Practical difference between parser rules and lexer rules in ANTLR?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4297770/practical-difference-between-parser-rules-and-lexer-rules-in-antlr)