# How to match a simplistic string in ANTLR3

Tags: antlr, antlr3

I have the following Grammar. It should recognize a string delimited by the single quote character (`'`). However, this does not work as intended. In ANTLWorks, the console window shows the following warning:

> [10:46:50] error(139): Test.g:9:15: 
>   set complement is empty

Why is that and how can I match a string which can contain any charcters but the delimiter?

```
grammar Test;
options 
{

    language=CSharp3;
    output=AST;
    ASTLabelType=CommonTree;
}
string: '\'' (~('\''))* '\'';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must realize there's a strict separation between tokenizing and parsing in ANTLR. Your `string` rule should be a lexer rule, which should then be used in a parser rule:

```
grammar Test;

parse  : STRING EOF;

STRING : '\'' (~('\''))* '\'';
```

Also see: [Practical difference between parser rules and lexer rules in ANTLR?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4297770/practical-difference-between-parser-rules-and-lexer-rules-in-antlr)