# ANTLR gramar to detect ambiguous tokens

Tags: antlr, grammar, antlrworks

I'm creating a simple grammar in ANTLR to match somekind of commands. I'm stuck with tokens which use special characters.

Those commands would match sentences like...

1. `connect "HAL" computer 4`
2. `connect "HAL256" computer 8`
3. `connect "HAL2⁸" computer 16`
4. `connect "HAL 9000" computer 32`
5. `connect "HAL \x0A25 | 32" computer 64`

... to produce something like:

[image: interpretation]

It's clear that my problem is in the ID token, but I don't know how to solve it. Here is my current grammar:

```
grammar foo;
ID      :   '"' ('\u0000'..'\uFFFF')+ '"' ;
NUMBER  :    ('0'..'9')* ;
SENTENCE    :    'connect ' ID ' computer' NUMBER ;
```

How could I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of issues with your grammar:

1. `NUMBER` matches an empty string: lexer rules must always match at least 1 character
2. `SENTENCE` should be a parser rule (see: [Practical difference between parser rules and lexer rules in ANTLR?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4297770/practical-difference-between-parser-rules-and-lexer-rules-in-antlr))
3. `('\u0000'..'\uFFFF')+` also matches a `'"'`, which you most probably son't want

Try something like this instead:

```
sentence   : K_CONNECT ID K_COMPUTER NUMBER;

K_CONNECT  : 'connect';
K_COMPUTER : 'computer';
ID         : '"' (~'"')+ '"';
NUMBER     : ('0'..'9')+;
SPACE      : (' ' | '\t' | '\r' | '\n')+ {skip();};
```

Comment: Thanks Bart, great answer. However your third premise is wrong and one of my main concerns. I also would like to match something like:
connect "HAL"2"56" computer 8
(sorry for not having added to the question).

Comment: @Alfre2, that sounds like a nightmare to handle. That would mean that the first quote and the last quote in the entire input could be a single token? Is this an existing language you're parsing? If not, and you have a say in the matter, I highly recommend you do not support such an ugly (and confusing) token.

Comment: Hmmm... I'll heed your advise, you helped me a lot. 
I obtain those commands from a text file, they really can contain any character inside the name between quotes token. I think I'll pre-treat them before use my ANTLR parser, in this case your solution will work.