# Mutually left-recursive lexer rules on ANTL4?

Tags: antlr, antlr4, lexer

I'm trying to write Swift language highlight. Also I would like to highlight in addition to tokens of some language constructs. Having problems with the following rule:

```
Type
   : '[' Type ']'   
   | '[' Type ':' Type ']' 
   | (Attributes? Function_type_argument_clause 'throws'? '->' Type | Attributes? Function_type_argument_clause 'rethrows' '->' Type)
   | (Type_name Generic_argument_clause? | Type_name Generic_argument_clause? '.' Type)
   | Tuple_type
   | Type '?' 
   | Type '!' 
   | (Type_name Generic_argument_clause? | Type_name Generic_argument_clause? '.' Type) '&' Protocol_composition_continuation 
   | (Type '.' 'Type' | Type '.' 'Protocol')
   | 'Any' 
   | 'Self' 
   | '(' Type ')'
   ;
```

Error: *The following sets of rules are mutually left-recursive [Type]*

Tried to leave in the rule, only the following cases:

```
Type
   : Type '?' 
   | 'Any' 
   | 'Self' 
   ;
```

But the problem remained: *The following sets of rules are mutually left-recursive [Type]*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You defined `Type` as a lexer rule. Lexer rules cannot be left recursive. `Type` should be a parser rule.

See: [Practical difference between parser rules and lexer rules in ANTLR?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4297770/practical-difference-between-parser-rules-and-lexer-rules-in-antlr)

Note that there are existing Swift grammars:

- https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/blob/master/swift2/Swift2.g4
- https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/blob/master/swift3/Swift3.g4

Note that these grammars are user-comitted, test them properly!

### EDIT

> I'm still unable to understand it from the point of view of lexical analysis

Oh, you're only tokenising? Well, then you can't use `Type` as you're doing it now. You will have to rewrite it so that there is no left recursion any more.

For example, let's say the simplified `Type` rule looks like this:

```
Type
   : '[' Type ']'   
   | '[' Type ':' Type ']' 
   | Type '?' 
   | Type '!' 
   | 'Any' 
   | 'Self' 
   | '(' Type ')'
   ;
```

then you should rewrite it like this:

```
Type
   : TypeStart TypeTrailing?
   ;

fragment TypeStart
   : '[' Type ']' 
   | '[' Type ':' Type ']'
   | 'Any'
   | 'Self'
   | '(' Type ')'
   ;

fragment TypeTrailing: [?!];
```

Comment: I understand You. What do I do with syntax highlighting? I'm still unable to understand it from the point of view of lexical analysis - find the desired token and highlighted. And how to do it with parser rule?

Comment: @jeudesprit check my EDIT