# ANTLR4 input grammar

Tags: grammar, antlr4, bnf

How can I write this grammar expression for ANTLR4 input?

Originally expression:

```
<int_literal> = 0|(1 -9){0 -9}
<char_literal> = ’( ESC |~( ’|\| LF | CR )) ’

<string_literal> = "{ ESC |~("|\| LF | CR )}"
```

I tried the following expression:

```
int_literal : '0' | ('1'..'9')('0'..'9')*;
char_literal : '('ESC' | '~'('\'|'''|'LF'|'CR'))';
```

But it returned:

```
syntax error: '\' came as a complete surprise to me

syntax error: mismatched input ')' expecting SEMI while matching a rule
unterminated string literal
```

Comment: Can you edit your question and add what you’ve tried?

Comment: No problem Lucas, always be sure to post your effort and exact error messages here: that way you are most likely to get helpful answers. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Your quotes don't match:

```
'('ESC' | '~'('\'|'''|'LF'|'CR'))'
^ ^   ^   ^ ^ ^ ^ 
| |   |   | | | |
o c   o   c o c error
```

*`o` is open, `c` is close*

I'd read `"{ ESC |~("|\| LF | CR )}"` as this:

```
// A string literal is zero or more chars other than ", \, \r and \n
// enclosed in double quotes
StringLiteral
 : '"' ( Escape | ~( '"' | '\\' | '\r' | '\n' ) )* '"'
 ;

Escape
 : '\\' ???
 ;
```

Also note that ANTLR4 has short hand char classes (`[0-9]` equals `'0'..'9'`), so you can do this:

```
IntLiteral
 : '0' 
 | [1-9] [0-9]*
 ;

StringLiteral
 : '"' ( Escape | ~["\\\r\n] )* '"'
 ;
```

Also not that lexer rules start with an uppercase letter! Otherwise they become parser rules (see: [Practical difference between parser rules and lexer rules in ANTLR?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4297770/practical-difference-between-parser-rules-and-lexer-rules-in-antlr)).