# Supporting binary operator and quotes in ANTLR grammar

Tags: antlr, antlr4

We are trying to parse queries in the following form:

```
Taiwan OR China
Taiwan OR "Republic of China"
```

Essentially binary operators like OR/AND/NOT would be used to construct such queries and quotes are used to mark a term that contains multiple words. Our goal is then to extract the individual names here:

- **Taiwan** and **China** in the first case
- **Taiwan** and **Republic of China** in the second case

(The problem is more complex but this is a first milestone)

Starting with the basics, we would have the following for the first use case

```
grammar Query;
parse : expr EOF ;
expr : name binop name ;
binop : 'AND' | 'OR' | 'NOT' ;
name
  :  WORD
  ;
WORD              : ('a' .. 'z' | 'A' .. 'Z')+ ;
WS : [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip ;
```

When trying to expand this to capture quotes and handle spaces for terms within quotes we struggled a bit.

We tried something like this:

```
grammar Query;
parse : expr EOF ;
expr : name binop name ;
binop : 'AND' | 'OR' | 'NOT' ;
name
  :  WORD
  | '"' NAME_WITH_SPACES '"'
  ;
WORD              : ('a' .. 'z' | 'A' .. 'Z')+ ;
NAME_WITH_SPACES  : ('a' .. 'z' | 'A' .. 'Z' | ' ')+ ;
WS : [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip ;
```

More specifically, the output is:

```
line 1:0 mismatched input 'TAIWAN OR CHINA' expecting {'"', WORD}
```

respectively:

```
line 1:0 extraneous input 'TAIWAN OR ' expecting {'"', WORD}
line 1:29 mismatched input '<EOF>' expecting {'AND', 'OR', 'NOT'}
```

We appreciate there might be friction when attempting to contain spaces within quotes, while at the same time skipping them outside quotes.

Any ideas would be welcome - being new two this it's hard to tell how to accommodate these conflicting requirements around whitespace.

Answer (score 1):

No, this:

```
name
  :  WORD
  | '"' NAME_WITH_SPACES '"'
  ;

...

NAME_WITH_SPACES  : ('a' .. 'z' | 'A' .. 'Z' | ' ')+ ;
```

is not the same as:

```
name
  : WORD
  | NAME_WITH_SPACES
  ;

...

NAME_WITH_SPACES  : '"' ('a' .. 'z' | 'A' .. 'Z' | ' ')+ '"' ;
```

In the first case, input like `Taiwan OR "Republic of China"` is tokenised as follows:

- `Taiwan OR` (type: NAME_WITH_SPACES)
- `"`
- `Republic of China` (type: NAME_WITH_SPACES)
- `"`

because ANTLR's lexer rules try to match as much characters as possible. So if you let the quotes be included in the `NAME_WITH_SPACES` lexer rule:

```
NAME_WITH_SPACES  : '"' ('a' .. 'z' | 'A' .. 'Z' | ' ')+ '"' ;
```

then the input `Taiwan OR "Republic of China"` is  tokenised as  this:

- `Taiwan` (type: WORD)
- `OR` (type: OR)
- `"Republic of China"` (type: NAME_WITH_SPACES)

and spaces outside quoted tokens are properly skipped.

Note that you can write it like this:

```
WORD              : [a-zA-Z]+ ;
NAME_WITH_SPACES  : '"' [a-zA-Z ]+ '"' ;
```

Also see this related Q&A: [Practical difference between parser rules and lexer rules in ANTLR?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4297770/practical-difference-between-parser-rules-and-lexer-rules-in-antlr)

Comment: Great, that is a very useful thing to know and clear reasoning for this behaviour then! Thank you, Bart! (And thanks for the doc reference, something I'll get more in depth with)

Answer (score 0):

Further on this, we tried the following:

```
grammar Query;
parse : expr EOF ;
expr : name binop name ;
binop : 'AND' | 'OR' | 'NOT' ;
name
  : WORD
  | NAME_WITH_SPACES
  ;
WORD              : ('a' .. 'z' | 'A' .. 'Z')+ ;
NAME_WITH_SPACES  : '"' ('a' .. 'z' | 'A' .. 'Z' | ' ')+ '"' ;
WS : [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip ;
```

This seems to work reasonably well, even though to me it seems semantically identical with our first attempt which didn't work:

```
grammar Query;
parse : expr EOF ;
expr : name binop name ;
binop : 'AND' | 'OR' | 'NOT' ;
name
  :  WORD
  | '"' NAME_WITH_SPACES '"'
  ;
WORD              : ('a' .. 'z' | 'A' .. 'Z')+ ;
NAME_WITH_SPACES  : ('a' .. 'z' | 'A' .. 'Z' | ' ')+ ;
WS : [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip ;
```